# Cast text timestamp to datatype timestamp - PSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where all it's columns are of type text, there's a column called created and another called modified.

Both of them have timestamps with timezone but are of data type text.

[image]

I need to cast both of this columns to timestamp, but I've read there's no way to just "cast" to timestamp since PSQL doesn't allow it.

Any idea of a workaround to do this? I've been trying this:

```
to_timestamp(created) as created_user,
to_timestamp(modified) as modified_user,
```

but it throws a syntax error.

```
ERROR:  column "2017-02-22 16:30:06.79156 UTC" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT to_timestamp("2017-02-22 16:30:06.79156 UTC")
```

Any ideas what I can possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: Simple casts should work `SELECT '2017-02-22 16:30:06.79156 UTC'::timestamptz`. In your last select you used double quotes. Text between double quotes are identifiers like table and column names. Use single qoutes for string literals.

Comment: Regarding Eelke's comment on the double quotes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the way you call to_timestamp() which requires 2 parameters:

```
   CREATE TABLE Table1
        ("created" varchar(30), "modified" varchar(30))
    ;

    INSERT INTO Table1
        ("created", "modified")
    VALUES
        ('2017-02-22 16:30:06.79156 UTC', '2017-10-11 15:30:06.79156 UTC'),
        ('2017-04-21 16:30:06.79156 UTC', '2017-10-11 15:30:06.79156 UTC'),
        ('2017-04-19 16:30:06.79156 UTC', '2017-10-11 15:30:06.79156 UTC'),
        ('2017-05-23 16:30:06.79156 UTC', '2017-10-11 15:30:06.79156 UTC')
    ;
```

The shortcut method works, and so does the function to_timestamp(text, text) also works, e.g.

```
select
      created::timestamptz
    , modified::timestamptz
from table1;

select
      to_timestamp(created,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')
    , to_timestamp(modified,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.US')
from table1;

|                    created |                   modified |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| 2017-02-22T16:30:06.79156Z | 2017-10-11T15:30:06.79156Z |
| 2017-04-21T16:30:06.79156Z | 2017-10-11T15:30:06.79156Z |
| 2017-04-19T16:30:06.79156Z | 2017-10-11T15:30:06.79156Z |
| 2017-05-23T16:30:06.79156Z | 2017-10-11T15:30:06.79156Z |
```

But to_timestamp() without a second parameter fails:

```
select
      to_timestamp(created)
    , to_timestamp(modified)
from table1
;
```

> ERROR: function to_timestamp(character varying) does not exist Hint:
>   No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need
>   to add explicit type casts. Position: 15